# opening another handler from by ssh to remote host in python

Tags: python, linux, authentication, ssh

I have a controller that I ssh to with IP and password. Once I go to controller, I need to open another handler to access linux command. To access this handler, I need to log in as root and provide password.
How would I do that using ssh in python ?

```
Login to controller as
user: root
password: root
Inside Controller 
<cntrlprompt># logas root
Password:123456
After this step it would provide bash prompt
bash# ls -al
<capture ls -al output and return to main program.
```

This is very challenging for me and any help in this would be grateful. 
thanks

Comment: Try http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html .  Otherwise, look into pexpect or pty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) might be what you want. It's a python library that allows you to script shell interaction. This is an [example](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/ftp.py) illustrating an anonymous ftp session. It should be fairly easy to study it and build your own interaction scenario.

Comment: If I am running command and getting large output from that command, will pexpect be able to process it ?
How could I process that output and parse it. It is really large output ?

Comment: You have access to the command output through pexpect. Processing or parsing it, is up to you.

Comment: I am having trouble spawning ssh from apache httpd in python using pexpect ? Executing python alone works fine but not through apache.

Comment: So if I understand this right, the script you're trying to come up with is some backend for a webservice you would hit through apache? If yes, that would be a different issue and you would probably need to add more details about how you're having apache executing python scripts: mod_python, wsgi, plain cgi, etc., and some log or error messages if any.

Comment: I am executing this script just by saving it in /var/www/cgi-bin folder. calling it as http://localhost/cgi-bin/test1.py plain cgi>
malformed header from script. Bad header=name 'child' is not defined: test1.py, child is handler for session spawned

Comment: Could you open a new question and paste the code you wrote there and provide information about the environment you're running (OS, python version, etc.). It would make it easier to pinpoint the problem.